# what's the best way to initiate/create the xmlhttprequest (so that it works in the major browsers)?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

We all know that XMLHttpRequest is supported by all major browsers.

Go google and if you find many different snippets to initiate it.

The one I use is:

```
function getNewHTTPObject()
{
        var xmlhttp;

        /** Special IE only code ... */
        /*@cc_on
          @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
              try
              {
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
              }
              catch (e)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                  catch (E)
                  {
                      xmlhttp = false;
                  }
             }
          @else
             xmlhttp = false;
        @end @*/

        /** Every other browser on the planet */
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
        {
            try
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
}
```

Are there better ones ???

Really keen to embed the best way thanks.

Comment: Look at what the popular frameworks use: frameworks allow their users to write browser independent code. In fact, all this is much easier using for example JQuery's ajax... but if you insist on pure javascript (why?), checkout what it does behind the scenes.

Comment: pure javascript is correct. All I need to do is implement the 'fire and forget' pattern
why would I need a framework for that ?
no matter how light the framework might be is just silly

Comment: I'm not telling you to use a framework (but you should consider, as it solves your question in two lines of code and guarantees future compatibility), I'm telling you frameworks exist and do this. Either use them, or look at how they do it and redo it yourself (but WHY?)

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest method is to use a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which has all the cross-browser functionality you need.

Comment: very disappointing answer. Use JQuery !!!
you are lucky I ain't got enough reputation to vote you down.

Comment: @chacko: why is it disappointing? You did not say in your question that you did not want to use a framework. Developers have spent a considerable amount of time making sure jQuery ajax calls works across all browsers. Sounds as though you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @chacko: if you ask 'how can I do X in javascript so that it works in all browsers', why are you surprised people tell you to use a framework specially designed to do that? Why reinvent the wheel, and for each new browser (version) revisit and retest your code? This answer does not deserve to be voted down, it is not wrong. You shouldn't be downvoting answers because you don't like them...

Comment: I am amazed. Your argument would be valid for most of the javascript questions. 
How do I do this in javascript ? USE Jquery don't reinvent the wheel.